# header navbar doesn't move upwards

Tags: html, css

I had a problem regarding and HTML and CSS code...it used to work fine until I decided to add a class name for the `<ul>` and `<li>`  like this:

```
            <nav class="navContainer">

                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li class="leftSide navItem active"><a class=" home " href="#Home"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><br><span>Home</span></a></li>
                    <li class="leftSide navItem"><a class=" about scroll" href="#About"><i class="fas fa-id-card"></i><br><span>About Us</span></a></li>
                    <li class="middle navItem"><a class=" service scroll" href="#Services"><i class="fas fa-bolt"></i><br><span>Our Services</span></a></li>
                    <li class="middle navItem"><a class=" work scroll" href="#Work"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i><br><span>Our work</span></a></li>
                    <li class="rightSide navItem"><a class=" products scroll" href="#Products"><i class="fas fa-solar-panel"></i><br><span>Our products</span></a></li>
                    <li class="rightSide navItem"><a class=" contact scroll" href="#Contact"><i class="fas fa-headset"></i><br><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>

                </ul>
           <nav>
```

this resulted to make the navbar to be vertical instead of horizontal until I edited the selectors in the CSS code like this:

```
/* header st */

.mainContainer header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #45af0d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 256px;
}


/* navBar st */

.mainContainer header .navContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 696px;
    list-style: none;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem {
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f1f2f6;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem {
    --border-color: #f1f1f1;
    --border-width: 5px;
    --bottom-distance: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--border-color), var(--border-color));
    background-size: 0% var(--border-width);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #f1f2f6;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-size 200ms;
    background-position: 50% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.rightSide {
    background-position: 100% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.middle {
    background-position: 50% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.leftSide {
    background-position: 0 calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance))
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li:hover {
    background-size: 100% var(--border-width);
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.active {
    background-size: 100% var(--border-width);
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem a i {
    color: #f1f2f6;
    font-size: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem span {
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
}


/* navbar ed */


/* header ed */
```

the cause of naming the classes is for a Jquery code for active navbar switching during scrolling

the final result of the change finally is like this:
[image: descreption]

`li` elements are not in the right place

I even deleted all `margin-top` that are relatable to the header except for the SVG.

Am I missing something?

Comment: most simple solution is to add "display: flex" to the ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens as names of styles are changed and previous rules cannot be applied. So try to edit name of rules from:

```
.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar { ... }

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem { ...}
```

to

```
nav.navContainer ul.navbar { ... }

nav.navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem { ... }
```

and set  `max-height` property to the size of the header which is 256px

An example:

```css
/* header st */

.mainContainer header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #45af0d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 256px;
}


/* navBar st */

.mainContainer header .navContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

nav.navContainer ul.navbar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 696px;
  max-height: 256px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav.navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f1f2f6;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem {
  --border-color: #f1f1f1;
  --border-width: 5px;
  --bottom-distance: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--border-color), var(--border-color));
  background-size: 0% var(--border-width);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #f1f2f6;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-size 200ms;
  background-position: 50% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.rightSide {
  background-position: 100% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.middle {
  background-position: 50% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.leftSide {
  background-position: 0 calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance))
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li:hover {
  background-size: 100% var(--border-width);
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.active {
  background-size: 100% var(--border-width);
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem a i {
  color: #f1f2f6;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem span {
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
}


/* navbar ed */


/* header ed */
```

```html
<nav class="navContainer">

    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="leftSide navItem active"><a class=" home " href="#Home"><i
            class="fas fa-home"></i><br><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class="leftSide navItem"><a class=" about scroll" href="#About"><i class="fas fa-id-card"></i><br><span>About
            Us</span></a></li>
      <li class="middle navItem"><a class=" service scroll" href="#Services"><i class="fas fa-bolt"></i><br><span>Our
            Services</span></a></li>
      <li class="middle navItem"><a class=" work scroll" href="#Work"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i><br><span>Our
            work</span></a></li>
      <li class="rightSide navItem"><a class=" products scroll" href="#Products"><i
            class="fas fa-solar-panel"></i><br><span>Our products</span></a></li>
      <li class="rightSide navItem"><a class=" contact scroll" href="#Contact"><i
            class="fas fa-headset"></i><br><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>

    </ul>
  <nav>
```

Comment: your snippet worked didn't change anything. However, I found the core solution which is setting max-height to 256px in the ``.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar`` selector which is the actual height of the header...I don't know how I missed that. But I'll edit your answer with the right solution and accept the answer...Thanks for your help

Comment: @HuangLinBao Thanks. However, if you click `Run Code snippet`, then `li` is horizontally aligned. Thanks again for accepted answer

Comment: that's what I wanted...the initial problem was that they were aligned vertically instead. until I started changing the selectors and names in the css file

Comment: I edited my question because the image description in the picture provided didn't appear so I added it

Answer (score -1):

```css
/* header st */

.mainContainer header {
  position: fixed;    **/*I think you should change you Position property*/**
  top: 0;
  background-color: #45af0d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 256px;
}


/* navBar st */

.mainContainer header .navContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

nav.navContainer ul.navbar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 696px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav.navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f1f2f6;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem {
  --border-color: #f1f1f1;
  --border-width: 5px;
  --bottom-distance: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--border-color), var(--border-color));
  background-size: 0% var(--border-width);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #f1f2f6;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-size 200ms;
  background-position: 50% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.rightSide {
  background-position: 100% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.middle {
  background-position: 50% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.leftSide {
  background-position: 0 calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance))
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li:hover {
  background-size: 100% var(--border-width);
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.active {
  background-size: 100% var(--border-width);
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem a i {
  color: #f1f2f6;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.mainContainer header .navContainer ul.navbar li.navItem span {
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
}


/* navbar ed */


/* header ed */
```

```html
<nav class="navContainer">

    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="leftSide navItem active"><a class=" home " href="#Home"><i
            class="fas fa-home"></i><br><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class="leftSide navItem"><a class=" about scroll" href="#About"><i class="fas fa-id-card"></i><br><span>About
            Us</span></a></li>
      <li class="middle navItem"><a class=" service scroll" href="#Services"><i class="fas fa-bolt"></i><br><span>Our
            Services</span></a></li>
      <li class="middle navItem"><a class=" work scroll" href="#Work"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i><br><span>Our
            work</span></a></li>
      <li class="rightSide navItem"><a class=" products scroll" href="#Products"><i
            class="fas fa-solar-panel"></i><br><span>Our products</span></a></li>
      <li class="rightSide navItem"><a class=" contact scroll" href="#Contact"><i
            class="fas fa-headset"></i><br><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>

    </ul>
  <nav>
```

Comment: I think your should change your position property.